# Different Column values not displayed in PYGTK TreeView

Tags: python, user-interface, treeview, pygtk

I executed this program :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

class CellRenderer:
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window()
        window.set_default_size(200,200)

        liststore = gtk.ListStore(str, str)
        liststore.append(["Fedora","http://fedoraproject.org"])
        liststore.append(["Slackware","http://www.slackware.com"])
        liststore.append(["Sidux","http://sidux.com"])

        treeview = gtk.TreeView(liststore)
        column_text = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Distributions")
        column_sample= gtk.TreeViewColumn("Links")
        treeview.append_column(column_text)
        treeview.append_column(column_sample)

        cellrenderer_text = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column_text.pack_start(cellrenderer_text,False)
        column_text.add_attribute(cellrenderer_text,"text",0)

        cellrenderer_sample = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column_sample.pack_start(cellrenderer_sample, False)
        column_sample.add_attribute(cellrenderer_sample,"text", 0)

        window.connect("destroy", lambda q : gtk.main_quit())
        window.add(treeview)
        window.show_all()

CellRenderer()
gtk.main()
```

The resultant window I obtained is this :

[image]

As you may have noticed, the lists appended to `liststore` had links in the second index.Why weren't any of those links displayed in the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to same index at

```
column_sample.add_attribute(cellrenderer_sample,"text", 0)
```

change it to

```
column_sample.add_attribute(cellrenderer_sample,"text", 1)
```

Full file.

```
import gtk

class CellRenderer:
    def __init__(self):
       window = gtk.Window()
       window.set_default_size(200,200)

       liststore = gtk.ListStore(str, str)
       liststore.append(["Fedora","http://fedoraproject.org"])
       liststore.append(["Slackware","http://www.slackware.com"])
       liststore.append(["Sidux","http://sidux.com"])

       treeview = gtk.TreeView(liststore)
       column_text = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Distributions")
       column_sample= gtk.TreeViewColumn("Links")
       treeview.append_column(column_text)
       treeview.append_column(column_sample)

       cellrenderer_text = gtk.CellRendererText()
       column_text.pack_start(cellrenderer_text,False)
       column_text.add_attribute(cellrenderer_text,"text",0)

       cellrenderer_sample = gtk.CellRendererText()
       column_sample.pack_start(cellrenderer_sample, False)
       column_sample.add_attribute(cellrenderer_sample,"text", 1)

       window.connect("destroy", lambda q : gtk.main_quit())
       window.add(treeview)
       window.show_all()

CellRenderer()
gtk.main()
```